# Is it better to process a batch of images in one request or multiple in Symfony2?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm fetching a batch of images from Dropbox to my server (with Symfony). Once on my server, the copied images (copied via `copy()`) have their exif data read and some values returned to the server.

The user has input into the browser which images they want to use. So the browser could send an array of images to Symfony or send them one at a time (making multiple ajax requests).

I'm wondering whether it's better to send multiple smaller requests, or one big request. My concern is that Symfony would time out during the `copy('http://dropbox.com/file', '/var/local/file.jpg')`

Is there a best practice for calling heavy symfony scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're transferring small amounts of data (you're not uploading an image via ajax), its better to ferry that data in one request rather than in multiple requests - which would 1) create unnecessary traffic on your network and 2) add unnecessary complexity to your application (ie, another possible point of failure).

Ideally, you should get all of the data at one time, then add it to a queue (ie, RabbitMQ) and then process that data independently of the running Symfony process. That way the end user is not dependent on the processing of the data and you're no longer blocking the process by waiting on connection.

Comment: thanks. Would it change your opinion if I said I am actually copying multiple 10mb jpegs from dropbox to my server inside the ```copy()``` method? so in one request the server may be saving 100's mbs of images. I like your queuing concept best though, but until then what do you think?

Comment: I think that copying multiple 10MB JPGs further reinforces the need for a queue and a separate running process to process that queue (remember that PHP is blocking - thus, you're blocking the server, hogging the network and it would be very easy to DOS your server by making multiple requests at once - if not just to degrade service for other users waiting for a response)